# How to move an object to the other stable object in THREE.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to this and have created scene,renderer,camera,and two objects ,
what I want is to move one object to the other object how can I achieve that in THREE.JS ? 
heres all the stuff i have tried kindly help me in this 
thanks

```js
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/tween.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script> 
    var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000),
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera),
        tween = new TWEEN.Tween({cube.position})
   .to({cube1.position},3000)
   .delay(2000)
   .start();  
    
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
     
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.CubeGeometry(2,2,2),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true, color: 0x000000}
    ));
    cube.position.x=3;
    cube.position.y=1;
    cube.position.z=2;
    //cube.geometry.dynamic = True;
    //cube.translateZ( 10 );
    scene.add(cube); 

    camera.position.z = 10;

    var dullMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xCCFF00  , ambient: 0x333333 } );
     
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('models/monkey.js', function (geometry, materials) {
        cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, dullMaterial );
        scene.add(cube1);
    });

    var render = function () { 
        requestAnimationFrame(render); 
        controls.update();
        TWEEN.update();

        cube1.rotation.x += 0.01; 
        cube1.rotation.y += 0.01;
        //cube.translate(0.1);
        renderer.render(scene, camera); 
    }; 
    render(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another library tween.js (you can find it in three.js\examples\js\libs) and do

```
new TWEEN.Tween( object1.position, // old position
    .to( object2.position, 3000 ) // new position, duration
    .delay( 2000 )
    .start();
```

Comment: kindly do let me know where to add this ? i didn't get you please explain in detail it would be of great help Thanks @gaitat

Comment: Actually you can put it anyplace after the objects have been created. The `delay` parameter will take care of the start of the animation and the `duration` will tell the animation how long to last.

Comment: [https://code.createjs.com/] from here i got that library and when i added this above code and refresh browser my objects were no longer there :( @gaitat

Comment: You should use the one in `three.js\examples\js\libs` as I said in my post. there are a lot of tween libs out there.

Comment: kindly proved a link so i can directly go there three.js/examples link please @gaitat

Comment: it actually made my object disappear let me share code with you i hope that would help you understand the problem @gaitat.

Comment: i have shared my code with you kindly find me the errors and help me improve please thanks .@gaitat

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? I would like to play with the code and the one above is not editable.

Comment: Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Comment: it would not be possible as of now as i have never tried jsfiddle , kindly some help through the above code snippet please

Comment: forgot to tag you :) @gaitat

Comment: you are creating the tween before cube and cube1 have been instantiated.

Comment: its not working i guess i have to start up from the start . create a new scene and look into every possible way to move one object to my second object. @gaitat thanks for your time